# Erro em classe de SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

O que estou fazendo mal nesta classe  de SQLite ? Estou recebendo este erro:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqllitetest/com.example.sqllitetest.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _dataFROMtestsWHERE 1
```

Este e a class de SQLite  :

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tests.db";
public static final String TABLE_TESTS = "tests";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_DATA = "_data";
public static final String COLUMN_DISCIPLINA = "_disciplina";


public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TESTS  + " ( "+
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_DATA + " TEXT ," +
            COLUMN_DISCIPLINA + " TEXT "
            +");";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_TESTS);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}

public void addTest (Testes test){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_DATA,test.get_data());
    values.put(COLUMN_DISCIPLINA,test.get_disciplina());
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_TESTS,null,values);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();



}

public void deleteTest ( String data, String disciplina){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " WHERE" + COLUMN_DATA + "=\""  + data + "\"" + "OR" + COLUMN_DISCIPLINA + "=\"" + disciplina +"\";" );
}

public String printDisciplina (){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_DISCIPLINA + " FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " WHERE 1";


    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("disciplina"))!=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("disciplina"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }


    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return dbString;
}
public String printData (){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_DATA + "FROM" + TABLE_TESTS + "WHERE 1";


    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data"))!=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("data"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }


    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

}

Main activity :

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textDisciplina;
TextView textData;
EditText disciplina;
EditText data;
Button addButton;
Button removeButton;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textDisciplina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisciplina);
    textData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textData);
    disciplina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.disciplina);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(MainActivity.this,null,null,1);


    addButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Testes teste = new Testes(data.getText().toString(),disciplina.getText().toString());
            dbHandler.addTest(teste);
            printDataBase();
        }

    });

    removeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String data_input = data.getText().toString();
            String disciplina_input = data.getText().toString();
            dbHandler.deleteTest(data_input,disciplina_input);
            printDataBase();
        }
    });

    printDataBase();
}



public void printDataBase(){
    String date = dbHandler.printData();
    String discipline = dbHandler.printDisciplina();
    textDisciplina.setText(discipline);
    textData.setText(date);
    data.setText("");
    disciplina.setText("");

}
```

}

Comment: `COLUMN_DISCIPLINA`  tem que valor?

Comment: Tem o valor que o user mete no MainActivity. Bem se calhar  e melhor postar o mainActivity

Comment: Não é necessário. Basta saber que valor ele está a receber

Comment: Nao percebi, sou um pouco novato no android

Comment: Indique aqui o erro que está a dar, assim como a linha, para eu saber qual é o problema que apresenta neste momento

Comment: 07-09 15:46:14.072 24048-24048/com.example.sqllitetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.sqllitetest, PID: 24048
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Esse é o erro, não tou tendo erro no programa mas essa exceção

Comment: `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("disciplina"))` tenta obter o valor para o campo `disciplina` que não existe. o seu chama-se `_disciplina`. Faça antes `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DISCIPLINA ))` e o mesmo acontece para o `printData`

Comment: Fiz isso ja nao da erro mas a aplicação fica toda branca e em loop sem erros! Obrigado por todo seu trabalho e paciência comigo !

Comment: Não tem problema, acontece que tinha vários erros por isso é sempre mais demorado a conseguir corrigir todos. Mas esse era um deles, os campos a serem pesquisados não coincidiam com os que tinha nas tabelas. Mas dá algum erro? aparece alguma coisa no log? Aconselho também a tentar fazer debug e ver se cada método está a apanhar os valores pretendidos. E vejo também que não tem `c.moveToFirst()` no código editado

Comment: Nao no LogCat fica so fazendo Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated , infinitamente

Comment: Ja consegui fazer funcionar mas fica uma grande barafunda o importante e funcionar porque era so um teste para uma app maior que necessita de SQL para funcionar.

Comment: Se já funciona já esta no bom caminho. Agora é ir modificando para ficar da forma que quer. Resto de boa programação :)

Comment: Muito obrigado vlw! Muito melhor explicador que aqueles com muitos pontos arrogantes! Desejo muita sorte aqui no StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observando a mensagem de erro vemos que o SQL está todo junto:

```
SELECT _dataFROMtestsWHERE 1
```

Quando deveria ser:

```
SELECT _data FROM tests WHERE 1
```

Esta consulta provem de:

```
String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_DATA + "FROM" + TABLE_TESTS + "WHERE 1";
```

Que deve passar a ser:

```
public String printData (){
    ...
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_DATA + " FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " WHERE 1";
```

Repare bem nos espaços colocados entre as palavras `FROM` e `WHERE`.

Ainda falta no entanto corrigir o WHERE pois tem de ser `WHERE campo = 1`. Tem agora de ver qual o campo com o valor que quer que tenha 1.

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu o problema! Mas agora estou tendo este erro: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Falta `c.moveToFirst()` antes do `while` para garantir que começa a pesquisa no primeiro valor

Comment: agora me da este erro :  Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Comment: Qual é o erro ? CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ? em que linha. E confirme que corrigiu o where também porque eu suspeito que a sua consulta não está a devolver nenhum resultado. Para saber se tem resultados pode usar `c.getCount()` que lhe diz quantas linhas foram obtidas

Comment: Eu meti "WHERE" + "COLUMN_ID" + "=" + "1"

Comment: mple.sqllitetest E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 1 columns. Esse é o erro que me da .

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta para contemplar esses factos todos.

Comment: Ok obrigado, ja editei a pergunta para o que meti.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que por um espaço no from e no where, se n dá erro de sintaxe porque quando ele vai executar o comando ele tenta ler tudo junto.

aonde ta errado:

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_DATA + **"FROM"** + TABLE_TESTS + **"WHERE 1"**;

Correto:

```
public String printData (){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_DATA + " FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " WHERE 1";
```